# Converting Javascript member variable to Typescript member variable

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to work out how to convert the member variables of my Javascript code to the Typescript equivalent.

In my Javascript code, after the `constructor()` I have:

```
this.theMediaItem = [];
this.theMediaItem.embedLink = '';
this.theMediaItem.username = '';
```

I have tried the following as the Typescript equivalent, inserted as required between the `export class` and the `constructor()` but it doesn't like the '.':

```
theMediaItem = [];
theMediaItem.embedLink = '';
theMediaItem.username = '';
```

Comment: Why do you define `theMediaItem` as array ?

Comment: Good question. What is the recommended way?

Comment: I guess you need to define it as simple object `this.theMediaItem = {};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use syntax below, also make sure you don't define your `theMediaItem` as array, because from usage I see that you assign its properties:

```
class YourClass {
    constructor() {
       this.theMediaItem = {};
       this.theMediaItem.embedLink = '';
       this.theMediaItem.username = '';
    }
}
```

or do it in simple way:

```
class YourClass {
    theMediaItem = { embedLink: '', username: '' },    
    constructor() {
       // ...
    }
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html

Comment: I am confused. I thought member variables (that can be accessed by this.xxx) had to be placed between class YourClass and constructor()

Comment: True, you can do it in simple way also, look updated answer.

Comment: That's great thanks. That is pretty much what I am trying to do. Brilliant!

Answer (score 4):

For what you are describing, here's one typescript equivalent:

```
interface MediaItemArray<T> extends Array<T> {
    embedLink?: string;
    username?: string;
}

class MyClass {
    theMediaItem: MediaItemArray<any> = [];

    constructor() {
        this.theMediaItem.embedLink = "";
        this.theMediaItem.username = "";
    }
}
```

That's kind of strange though... you probably don't want to use an array and it's best to just have properties directly on the class:

```
class MediaItem {
    embedLink = "";
    username = "";
}
```

Or described in an interface:

```
interface MediaItem {
    embedLink: string;
    username: string;
}
```

Then, as you say in the comments, if you have a view you can add it as a property like so:

```
class MyView {
    mediaItem = new MediaItem()
}
```

Or if you are using an interface:

```
class MyView {
    mediaItem: MediaItem = {
        embedLink: "",
        username: ""
    };
}
```

Comment: The reason for doing it that way was for clarity in the view html code when I insert theMediaItem.embedLink and theMediaItem.username.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the 'dictionary' pattern? 
Please refer the TS document and wiki page below.

interface Dictionary { [index: string]: string; }

https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Interfaces%20in%20TypeScript&referringTitle=TypeScript%20Documentation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array#Example